# « Il » ou « celui-ci », « elle » ou « celle-ci » comme pronoms de reprise de compagnies, d’entreprises, de sociétés?

Tags: formulation, reformulation, pronom-de-reprise

- Exemple 1 : Pourriez-vous me donner le nom du transporteur qui est chargé de livrer mon colis au Canada afin que je puisse prendre contact avec

…celui-ci.

…lui.

- Exemple 2 : Pourriez-vous me donner le nom de la compagnie qui est chargée de livrer mon colis au Canada afin que je puisse prendre contact avec

…celle-ci.

…elle.

D’autres tournures à proposer?

Comment: Avec *… lui, … elle* le ton est plus fluide, naturel. Avec *celle-ci (icelle moyenâgeuse)* ou *celui-ci (icelui)*, le ton est officiel plutôt juridique, voire inquisitorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je dirais

> Pourriez-vous me donner le nom du transporteur qui est chargé de livrer mon colis au Canada afin que je puisse le contacter.

> Pourriez-vous me donner le nom de la compagnie qui est chargée de livrer mon colis au Canada afin que je puisse la contacter.

Sinon

> Pourriez-vous me donner le nom du transporteur qui est chargé de livrer mon colis au Canada afin que je puisse prendre contact avec lui.

> Pourriez-vous me donner le nom de la compagnie qui est chargée de livrer mon colis au Canada afin que je puisse prendre contact avec elle.

Comment: Sinon, pour ce qui est de ma question, serait-ce préférable d’employer « il », « elle » ou « celui-ci », « celle-ci »?

Comment: @Priscilla Vu ma réponse éditée. (Non locuteur natif quand même:-)!)

Comment: @Priscilla Vu un article où elle s'emploie pour compagnie, enterprise https://www.cifinancial.com/ci-gam/ca/fr/expert-insights/articles/business-operations-corporation-vs-sole-proprietorship.html#:~:text=D'un%20point%20de%20vue,est%20sa%20propre%20entit%C3%A9%20juridique.